# WinRT CheckBox Properties

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

hello friends ı am trying to check if is checkbox checked or unchecked  if else  but its not let me to do look my code downBelow   all  I  want  check before ı turn the page   look it say "Window.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ToogleButton.Checked can only be appear left hand side of += or -= "

```
 private async void soru6to7_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        if(Soru6_CheckBox4.Unchecked)
         {  
           TestPageSoru6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
           };
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Checked** and **Unchecked** are events. I think you want to check the **[IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked)** property.

Comment: I know Checked and Unchecked are events And  I want one fonction and use this fonction for  4  checkbox  ı  mean  ı dont want write so meny code  for  each checked and unchecked  is so much

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [IsOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch.ison.aspx) property if this is a `ToggleSwitch` and the [IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) if this is a `ToggleButton`.

Comment: no Aeron Look I try CheckBox  And I only Want  this check Box İf Not Checked Button disable when click

Comment: If you are using events, register the same event handler for each registration you make.

Comment: Thx Aeron i registered for each checkbox checked event it fixed problem but  i ask question for if is there another short way because register for each event. Too much code thx anyway have a nice day